# Thread.sleep() not working in Jenkins Quiet Down mode

Tags: jenkins, groovy, java-threads

## Question

Every Wednesday we have a maintenance window between 05:00 and 07:00.  During this time we want to put Jenkins in *Quiet Down* mode so that it queues all builds.  I have the following method

```
@NonCPS
def doAndCancelQuietDown(reason, length) {
    echo "Entering quiet down mode... "

    length = length?.isInteger() ? length.toInteger() : 1
    reason = "$reason Downwtime is schedule for $length minutes."
    
    Jenkins.instance.doQuietDown(false, length,  reason)
                        
    Thread.sleep(length *  60 *  1000); // sleep for 2 hours
                        
    echo "Exiting quiet down mode... "
    Jenkins.instance.doCancelQuietDown()
}
```

This method works as intended when I set a length of 1, 5, 10, 20, etc.  It will put Jenkins in *Quiet Down* mode and then cancel *Quiet Down* mode after a specific amount of time passes.  However, when I try to run this with a value of 120 it will put Jenkins in *Quiet Down* mode but it will never remove it from *Quiet Down* mode.

I cannot use the Jenkins `sleep()` step because of a [CPS Method Mismatch](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/). Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I believe the [SleepStep.Execution](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-basic-steps/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/SleepStep.Execution.html) class may be helpful, but I can't seem to implement it.  I also believe this is a relevant JIRA [JENKINS-26120](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-26120) but the PR doesn't really tell me much

Comment: Why you put it into noncps?

Comment: @daggett if I don’t use that annotation it will pause the pipeline after it executed doQuietDown()